# Redirecting Console (stdout, standard error, etc.) output of a parent process to child process (reverse)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Usually people want to get the child process output, but I want to get the parent process output in child process.

Comment: What's the problem then? You have the parent process output in your control, after all?

Comment: @DannyChen - I assume a process started using `Process.Start`.

Comment: The parent process does Console.Writeline, and I cannot change that code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if [Console.SetOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) and [Console.SetError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror.aspx) solve your problem.